# Central store causes slolwness in gpmc and when you edit a gpo

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, group-policy

i created a central store because i was dealing with the point and print windows 2008 issue, the thing is some of my dc are behind slow vpns, so, in those dc when you try to edit a gpo with administrative templates take very long to load.

There is a way to fix this?, or there is a way i can remove the central store safely?

Answer (score 2):

You should be setting up Active Directory Sites and Services so that you only connect to Domain Controllers in your site. This will prevent you from trying to access DCs across the VPN link unless all of the DCs in your site are down.

You should be doing this for more than GPMC responsiveness, since it means that your client authentication traffic and GPO processing is happening across the VPN link as well.

Comment: The sites are created, and the dc are there, but the slownes continue

Comment: Are you sure that you're connecting to one across the VPN and that the slowness isn't because of some network issue within your site? How slow is slow? It should take maybe 5-6 seconds to open GPMC and load the central store.

Comment: i'm connecting to dc through avpn but i'm using rdp.  It takes like a couple of minutes

Comment: Ok, this is starting to not make much sense. Can you please draw a diagram of your network topology? Where are you running GPMC from? Your workstation or a DC that you've RDPed into?

Comment: i'm runnig the gpmc in the dc, at the other side of the vpn

Comment: Then the DC should have the central store locally and it should be opening that local copy. Have you verified that the DC that you're RDPing into actually has a copy of it in sysvol like it's supposed to? Have you verified that there are no connectivity or replication problems with `repadmin` or `dcdiag`? What is the resource utilization like on that DC?

Comment: Yes, there is a copy of the ADMX files into the local DC sysvol folder

Comment: As the blog is asking me to wrap this discution i ask this, there is a way remove safely the central store?

Comment: Just delete it. But this could be a symptom of a larger problem, like a DNS issue...

Comment: just delete the policiesdefinition folder, that's what i wanted to be sure of, ok, thank you very much you have been very nice.  Yes iknow this Domain isn't completely healthy and i have been alerting about that since a couple of years, the problem is the people behind this isn't very qualified